# If Hinduism don't support Incest then why did Krishna married his own cousin Mitravinda and Bhadra?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, identification-request

My Dear King, Lord Krishna Forcibly Took Away Princess Mitravindā, The Daughter Of His Aunt Rājādhidevī, Before The Eyes Of The Rival Kings”

Srimad Bhagavatam 10.58.31

Bhadrā Was A Princess Of The Kaikeya Kingdom And The Daughter Of Lord Krishna’s Paternal Aunt Śrutakīrti. The Lord Married Bhadrā When Her Brothers, Headed By Santardana, Offered Her To Him.”

Srimad Bhagavatam 10.58.56
Even if they were cross cousins but still isn't it wrong?

Comment: Cousin marriage seems to be common at the time. Arjuna also married his cousin Subhadra. Even Buddha's wife was his cousin.

Answer (score 1):

**manu smriti ch III.5 :**

> asapiṇḍā ca yā mātura**sagotrā ca yā pituḥ** | sā praśastā dvijātīnāṃ
> dārakarmaṇi maithune || 5 ||
>
> She who is not a “sapiṇḍa” of one’s mother, **not of the same “Gotra”
> as his Father**, and who is not born of (unlawful) intercourse—has
> been recommended for marriage.—(5)

As mitravinda and bhadra were daughters of paternal aunt, they will be of different gotra from krishna's father gotra, hence it was not wrong as per marriage rule.

Comment: But still, they were cousins

Comment: as per dharma shastras, prohibition of first cousin marriage applies only for brahmans. For kshatriyas, vaishyas, etc. it is not and only gotra rule applies for them as per baudhayana dharmashastra. Here arjuna, krishna, etc were kshatriya/gopa and hence inline with shastras.